# How to dissallow updates to a table if a column is a certain value in mysql?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I dont want anyone to be able to update thier Name to certain values and cancel the update if it is attempting to update the PLayername to "Error", and need to prevent it at the database level.

I figured I could simply do this with a trigger, so I tried making one here.

```
delimiter $$
create trigger errorcheck before insert on player_data
for each row
begin
if new.PlayerName = 'Error' then
signal sqlstate '45000';
end if;
end;$$
```

but the server responds with this error:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$$' at line 7

Thank you for any help / suggestions

Comment: Remove the semi-colon just before the `$$`

Comment: You could use a Stored Procedure

Comment: i removed the semicolon, but it did not change the error message

Answer (score 0):

```
delimiter $$
create trigger errorcheck before insert on player_data
for each row
begin
if new.PlayerName = 'Error' then
signal sqlstate '45000';
end if;
end;
```

I dont understand why but removing the $$ delimeter at the end saved the trigger and i tested it and it works how i wanted it to.